# Moving function from component.ts file into separate files in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and was wondering how to split a component class into multiple files. The component I am working on is becoming too large and I want to move the methods into separate files. But I am not sure the functions in new files, how will they access the class variables? I will try and explain my problem by giving a simple example:

**app.component.html**

```
<div (click)="onSelectOne()">
    One
</div>
<div  (click)="onSelectOne()">
    Two
</div>

<div (click)="onSelectOne()">
    Three
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    curr_login = "";
    selectedTool;
    websocket;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onSelectOne(){

    }

    onSelectTwo(){

    }

    onSelectThree(){

    }


}
```

Now I want to move 3 methods: `onSelectOne`, `onSelectTwo` and `onSelectThree` into 3 different files. How can I do that? Also, each function uses the class variables like `curr_login`, `websocket` or `dataService`, so I will need to somehow access these also in the new files.

**Edit**

This is just a sample example and not the real code. In my code, the component code has become really huge and that is why I want to move the functions into separate files.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: This is just a sample example, in my case the code has has become too long and already crossed more than 1000 lines, so I want to move the functions into separate files.

Comment: create a service and move it there

Comment: You shouldn't move these functions. But if they are complex, they can of course *delegate* to functions defined elsewhere. Thet can pass arguments to these functions, and get return values out of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should organize your files into modules (ngModules) according to Angular guidance:

https://angular.io/guide/module-types

There are 5 basic types of modules:

1. Domain Modules
2. Routed Modules
3. Routing Modules
4. Service Modules
5. Widget Modules

Modules have hierarchical relationships similar to class inheritance, where components, directives, and pipes can be private to the module, imported from other modules (i.e inheritance), or exported to form the module's public interface.

Services are usually contained within Service Modules (contains mostly services, no declarations), and leveraged a different way (different than the import/export system that components, directives and pipes use).  Services are registered with injectors (typically the root injector), and DI allows them to be injected anywhere in the application where DI is supported (i.e. service constructors, component constructors, module constructors)

My recommendation, if you have a lot of service files, is to start organizing your services into service modules (i.e a Core module) that are intended to be imported by the AppModule. You could have several Service modules organized by functional area.

If you have many widgets that are shared by several feature modules, I would recommend organizing them within one or more widget modules (contains mostly declarations, very few services).  These modules are intended to be imported by Domain feature modules.

Consider doing something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This we can achieve by creating common file and we can do the operations. And this is not best way but for the your this can be answer.

**util.ts**

```
export function onSelectOne(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket){
   console.log(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket);
}
export function onSelectTwo(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket){
   console.log(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket);
}
export function onSelectThree(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket){
   console.log(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket);
}
```

```js
//app.component.ts

import { onSelectOne, onSelectTwo, onSelectThree} from './utils';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    curr_login = "";
    selectedTool;
    websocket;
    onSelectOne = onSelectOne;
    onSelectTwo = onSelectTwo;
    onSelectThree = onSelectThree;
    
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div (click)="onSelectOne(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket)">One</div>
<div  (click)="onSelectOne(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket)">Two</div>
<div (click)="onSelectOne(curr_login, selectedTool, websocket)">Three</div>
```

But i would suggest to create service and do the necessary actions. that would be best approach.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    curr_login = "";
    selectedTool;
    websocket;

    
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    
    onSelection(clicked){
     // Here we can call service which will do task. and if all three same operation we can make more simpler code here.
     
     this.someService.checkSomethig(clicked, curr_login, selectedTool, websocket);
       
    }


}
```

```html
<div (click)="onSelection(1)">
  One
</div>
<div  (click)="onSelection(2)">
  Two
</div>
<div (click)="onSelection(3)">
  Three
</div>
```

i hope this will helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service to move your function into. You will benefit from DI and could reuse those functions where you want by injecting it from component constructor and such.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 0):

As per the Angular Guidelines, Component should not contain more than 400 lines of code. You need to move Business Logic from Component to Injectable Services. This will make your component lean. Component main functionality is

1) read the router params 
2) fetch the data from service and assign to DOM & Submit the data to Backend 
3) Template/Reactive Form Creation Logic 
4) Pass data to Child Component and trigger Change Detection. 
5) Receive data from Child Component and update the DOM 
6) Handle Template DOM Events and Redirects.

You can create a child component and move the logic common to those 3 methods. You can pass the Data using @Input and handle the events using @Output.